# Howto log each entity data with relations with Doctrine and Symfony2 Framework?

Tags: php, symfony, logging, doctrine, entity-relationship

I'll begin to a new PHP project that Doctrine ORM will be used on Symfony Framework.

I am thinking of the Entities and relations structure at the moment. It may totally sounds ridiculous and contradict to ORM logic ?

I haven't used Symfony and Doctrine before.

There will be so many Entities that each has many relations.

For ex.
 let's say I have 3 entities.

-User

-Post

-Comment

I have been asked for a structure like below by the Project Owner.

## log_entities

```
   Id           Type        CreatedAt    Status      title

   1           Post       Y-m-d H:i:s     1          Post 1...
   2           Comment    Y-m-d H:i:s     0          comment 1...
   3           Comment    Y-m-d H:i:s     1          comment 2...
   4           User       Y-m-d H:i:s     1          User X...
   ...         ...        ...             ...        ...
```

## rel_entities

```
from_log_id   fromContentType      toContentType    to_log_id
     2              Comment              Post           1
     3              Comment              Post           1
     1              Post                 User           4
```

Objects

```
User
   -id
   -name
   -log_id (fk)
   ...

Comment
   -id
   -connet
   -log_id (fk)
   ...

Post
   -id
   -content
   -log_id (fk)
   ...
```

-every object will have a log data on entities table.

-Reason of that is, we should be able to get all relations of an Object by a table easily.

How can a similar scenario like this should be done with Doctrine ?

Thank you.

Comment: I guess you can begin by read the [Doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html). Make sentences can help you by determine the relation, for instance. If one user can have many post  and one post belongs to only one user it's a relation ManyToOne.

Comment: I read documentation. But get confused. I could't decide which relation model i should use.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should name your PHP objects not in plural, but in singular, because they represent a single entity of the group. Then, the `entityId` field you are adding to each entity really does not make sense, as you have already an `id` field that represents exactly that.

For what I see, you need to define relationships between your entities. You can use `OneToOne`, `OneToMany`, `ManyToOne` and `ManyToMany`. Which one to use is up to the application specifications, but an example derived from your code:

```
User
  - id
  - name
  - comments (OneToMany -> Comment)
  - posts (OneToMany -> Post)

Comment
  - id
  - connet
  - user (ManyToOne -> User)

Post
  - id
  - content
  - user (ManyToOne -> User)
```

And so on. I don't understand your `entityId` at all, could you be more specific?

Comment: I've edit the question. There should be log of every entities data. And from that log i should make the relation and can take the entity data from that log_id. That's what i am asked for:)

Comment: You can create another entity called `Log` and add a ManyToMany relationship with every other entity. I still don't understand exactly what your problem is. You should try to write a better specification so maybe I can be of more use.